# Remover o primeiro elemento de uma lista duplamente encadeada - C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou com problema para remover o primeiro nó da minha lista duplamente encadeada. Eu criei uma função que retorna o tipo da lista (Value) para realizar a operação, ao mostrar os elementos da lista dentro da função é possível ver que ela realiza a remoção do primeiro elemento, contudo ao retornar ela para main e listar ela utilizando a função printList() ela parece mostrar o primeiro elemento que supostamente foi removido.

Segue o meu código completo abaixo. Desde já agradeço.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CLEAN "cls"
#define PAUSE "pause"

typedef struct Value{
  int value;
  struct Value *next;
  struct Value *prev;
} Value;

Value *list;

Value *start(){
  return NULL;
}

void freeList(Value *list){
    Value *v = list;
    while(v != NULL){
        printf("Liberando o canal: %d\n", v->value);
        Value *temp = v->next;
        free(v);
        v = temp;
    }
}

int isEmptyList(Value *list){
    return (list == NULL);
}

void menu(){
    printf("\t _______________________________________________________________");
    printf("\n\t|O que Voce Deseja Fazer?\t\t\t\t\t|\n\t|");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t|\n\t|[01] - Adicionar valor de forma ordenada;\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[02] - Adicionar valor no fim da lista;\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[03] - Listar todos os valores;\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[04] - Mostrar o maior valor;\t\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[05] - Mostrar o menor valor;\t\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[06] - Remover ultimo valor;\t\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[07] - Remover primeiro valor;\t\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|[08] - Sair;\t\t\t\t\t\t\t|");
    printf("\n\t|_______________________________________________________________|\n");
    printf("\t Opcao: ");
}

Value *insertOrdered(Value *list){
  int value;
  Value *aux = list;
  Value *aux2 = list;
  Value *new = (Value*) malloc(sizeof(Value));

  printf("Informe um valor: ");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  new->value = value;
  if(aux == NULL){
    new->next = aux;
    new->prev = NULL;
  }else{
    while(aux != NULL){
      if(new->value < aux->value){
        new->next = aux;
        if(aux->prev != NULL){
          aux2->next = new;
          aux->prev = new;
          new->prev = aux2;
          return list;
        }else{
          new->prev = NULL;
          aux->prev = new;
          return new;
        }
      }else if(aux->next == NULL){
        aux->next = new;
        new->prev = aux;
        new->next = NULL;
        return list;
      }
      aux2 = aux;
      aux = aux->next;
    }
  }
  return new;
}

Value *insertEnd(Value *list){
  int value;
  Value *aux = list;
  Value *new = (Value*) malloc(sizeof(Value));

  printf("Informe um valor: ");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  new->value = value;
  while(aux != NULL){
    if((aux->next == NULL) && (new->value > aux->value)){
      aux->next = new;
      new->prev = aux->next;
      new->next = NULL;
    }else if((aux->next == NULL) && (new->value < aux->value)){
      printf("O numero informado e menor que o ultimmo valor\n");
      printf("A ordem da lista sera comprometida\n");
      break;
    }
    aux = aux->next;
  }
  return new;
}

void printList(Value *list){
    Value *v = list;
    if(isEmptyList(v)){
        printf("Essa lista está vazia!\n");
    }
    else{
        while(v != NULL){
            printf("\nValor: %d\n", v->value);
            v = v->next;
        }
    }
}

void findBigger(Value *list){
  Value *v = list;
  while(v != NULL){
    if(v->next == NULL){
      printf("O maior valor da lista e: %d\n", v->value);
    }
    v = v->next;
  }
}

void findSmaller(Value *list){
  printf("O maior valor da lista e: %d\n", list->value);
}

Value *removeLast(Value *list){
    Value *v = list;
  if(isEmptyList(v)){
        printf("Essa lista está vazia!\n");
    }else{
    while(v != NULL){
      if(v->next == NULL){
        v->prev->next = NULL;
        printf("Ultimo elemento removido com sucesso\n");
        return list;
      }
      v = v->next;
    }
  }
}

Value *removeFirst(Value *list){
  Value *v = list;
  if(isEmptyList(v)){
        printf("Essa lista está vazia!\n");
    }else{
    if(v->next != NULL){
      v->next->prev = NULL;
    }
    list = v->next;
    v->next = NULL;
    printf("\nValor: %d\n", list->value);
    return list;
  }
}

int main(){

  int op;

  list = start();

  do{
    system(CLEAN);
    menu();
    scanf("%d", &op);
    switch(op){
    case 1:
      system(CLEAN);
      list = insertOrdered(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 2:
      system(CLEAN);
      insertEnd(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 3:
      system(CLEAN);
      printList(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 4:
      system(CLEAN);
      findBigger(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 5:
      system(CLEAN);
      findSmaller(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 6:
      system(CLEAN);
      removeLast(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 7:
      system(CLEAN);
      removeFirst(list);
      system(PAUSE);
      break;
    case 8:
      break;
    }
  }while(op != 8);

    system(CLEAN);
    printf("O programa esta liberando a memória\n");
    freeList(list);
    system(PAUSE);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosto da forma que estruturou seu programa, mas o seu problema acontece por causa de um mal entendido, ou falta de atenção na remoção tanto no caso de remover o primeiro elemento, quanto no caso de remover o último, segue abaixo como deveriam ser alguns detalhes destas funções, comentando onde você errou de forma comparativa.

---

```
Value *removeLast(Value *list)
Value *removeFirst(Value *list)
```

Primeiramente, se sua função não é utilizada para retornar nenhum valor, não defina que ela retorne nenhum valor. No seu código você apenas chama essas funções e o retorno dela não vai para lugar algum, não faça isso, tudo bem que no Windows não há nem warning, mas em outros casos há, e, particularmente, eu prefiro programar de forma a não causar warnings, mas não é um problema, só um conselho.

Outro problema nas declarações destas funções é que você passa um parâmetro cujo nome é idêntico ao de uma variável global, tudo bem que a variável que você passa como parâmetro quando chama estas funções é igual, e é mesmo recomendável que você crie funções genéricas, no caso, que aceite qualquer struct *Value*, e sua função pode acabar se confundindo quanto a usar a variável local ou a global sempre que você usa *list* nela. Eu particularamente **condeno** o uso de variáveis globais, mas se preferir continuar usando, não passe nenhum valor para essas funções, utilize *list* como variável global mesmo, ou mude o nome do parâmetro para torná-la mais genérica, ficando assim:

```
void removeLast()
void removeFirst()
```

---

Quanto ao ***removeLast***, você tem alguns problemas no fluxo.

Se a sua lista estiver vazia, você corretamente imprime que ela está vazia, se ela não estiver, você deve verificar se o "next" dela é diferente de NULL, porquê ai você sabe que esta lista não possui apenas um único valor e deve usar a variável *v* para percorrer a lista até encontrar o último *Value*.

Se não fizer esta verificação, não existirá "prev" para você fazer o "v->prev-next=NULL" e a referência de list continuará diferente de NULL também, apenas a referência local de *v* estará nula.

Então ficaria assim:

```
if(isEmptyList(v))
    printf("Essa lista está vazia!\n");
else if(v->next != NULL)
{
    /*É possível otimizar porquê já sabemos que o primeiro elemento não é o último,
    mas por didática vou deixar assim*/

    while(v != NULL) 
    {
        if(v->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("Ultimo elemento, %d, removido com sucesso\n",v->value);
            v->prev->next=NULL;
            free(v);
            return;
        }
        v = v->next;
    }
}
else
{
    ...
```

No caso do else, então, é apenas se a lista **não** estiver vazia mas o início dela já for o último, ou seja, ela contém apenas um valor, e, portanto, a própria *list* deve ser liberada e sua referência deve ser reiniciada, definindo ela como NULL ou iniciando ela pela função start() novamente, que é basicamente a mesma coisa:

```
else
{
    printf("Ultimo elemento, %d, removido com sucesso\n",list->value);
    free(list);
    list=start(); //list=NULL;
}
```

Perceba que definir *v* como NULL neste caso não seria correto, já que *list* ainda guardaria o endereço para a struct que foi liberada, que ainda está na memória. As outras operações como a de obter o valor usando v->value e free(v) ainda funcionaria, mas *list* ainda guardaria o endereço para a estrutura que você liberou.

É importante saber que a função *free()* não apaga os dados da memória, eles continuarão lá naquele endereço, a função free() apenas avisa ao Sistema Operacional que aquele espaço de memória pode ser usado para salvar outros dados, e portanto, qualquer acesso a essa área de memória é permitida, mas a qualquer momento pode ter dados que não são mais os que você colocou lá, e sim o que outros processos colocaram. A memória não é zerada quando você libera ela, você apenas **libera** ela, ela agora está disponível para ser utilizada por outros processos, o que você colocou lá ainda está lá até que seja sobrescrito por outro processo ou por você mesmo.

Portanto, se você não definir - no caso da lista conter apenas um elemento - que a própria variável *list* é NULL, tudo que for feito com a variável *list* ainda funcionará, como no seu caso, ainda irá imprimir na tela esse valor porquê você apenas permitiu que o SO sobrescreva as informações ali, elas não estão mais protegidas e isso pode causar efeitos indesejados.

---

O mesmo problema também ocorre para remover o primeiro elemento, ficaria assim:

```
if(isEmptyList(list))
    printf("Essa lista está vazia!\n");
else
{
    printf("\nValor Removido: %d\n", list->value);
    if(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        list = list->next;
        free(list->prev);
        list->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        free(list);
        list = start(); //list = NULL;
    }
}
```

mas no exemplo que você forneceu, na remoção do primeiro elemento, você acaba por destruir o acesso a todos os outros valores porquê você define que a lista é o próximo, e que o próximo dela é NULL. O correto a se fazer é basicamente liberar a raiz da lista, ou seja, a própria lista, mas fazer com que *list* agora seja o próximo dela, e que o próximo dela tenha anterior NULL, para não haver referência ao início original da lista. Fiz isto simplesmente movendo *list* para o próximo e liberando o "prev", que era a *list* anteriormente.

Observe que também há o problema da lista com um único elemento, porquê ela não terá "next" para fazer isso, então deve-se literalmente liberar a própria *list* e reiniciá-la usando *start*() ou atribuir para NULL.

---

Espero que estas considerações tenham lhe ajudado, qualquer dúvida continue explorando a plataforma, espero que você tenha aprendido mais sobre como é o funcionamento dos ponteiros e endereçamento, certamente meu detalhismo é confuso, as vezes é confuso até para quem já tem experiência com isso, então não se sinta mal, programação, principalmente em C, é assim mesmo!

Comment: Muito obrigado sua resposta foi de muita ajuda, também agradeço os conselhos, vou tentar para de usar variáveis globais hehe, e não tinha pensado em inicializar a lista novamente. Confesso que tive que ler mais de duas vezes algumas partes para entender o que você quis dizer, mas agora entendo mais sobre endereçamento.

Comment: Consegui fazer outro exercício que envolve a função de remover no inicio, meio ou fim, sem muitos problemas. Muito obrigado.